# Getting wordcount when using tinymce

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

I am using tinymce editor on the textarea. I am able to initialize the text editor but I now want to get the wordcount in the text editor on key press. Is there a easy way of getting the wordcount using the tiny mce when the user types the words.

Answer (score 3):

Very easy, there is already a plugin for that.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:wordcount

Example:

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "wordcount"
});
```

**Update**

Regarding your comment, you want a max limit on words. There are multiple solutions to this, and a lot of resources on the subject already. Check this out:

- [Tinymce text editor max char limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790474/tinymce-text-editor-max-char-limit)
- [How to limit number of characters/words](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How_to_limit_number_of_characters/words)
- [Limit the number of character in tinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342921/limit-the-number-of-character-in-tinymce)

Comment: There is another plugin that counts words and characters as well:  http://adamscheller.com/libraries/tinymce-count-words-plugin/