# How to limit characters in JFactory::getEditor - Joomla

Tags: joomla, tinymce, wysiwyg, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

```
$editor = & JFactory::getEditor();
$params = array('smilies'=> '0' ,'style'  => '0' ,'layer'  => '0' ,'table'  => '0' ,'clear_entities'=>'0');
$editor->display('description', $description , 550, 400, 60, 20, false, $params);
```

I use above code to generate a WYSIWYG editor in Joomla. Is there are way to limit character you enter in the editor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to limit the number of characters in an wysiwyg editor you will have to take into account that you may count the visible characters only or to count all characters (html overhead too). For tinymce there is a decription of the developers on how to count and limit characters/words (on submit): http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/How_to_limit_number_of_characters/words

If you want to limit the insertion of characters you will need to write an own [plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin) or configure your tinymce with some special functionality (functions).
Here are some helpfull ressources to get you started:

- http://www.ryann.ca/?p=186
- [Limit the number of character in tinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342921/limit-the-number-of-character-in-tinymce)
- http://pogostick.co.nz/limiting-character-count-with-tinymce/

Comment: It's also worth remembering that Joomla! allows the user to select the editor they use i.e. it may not always be tinyMCE... in fact it's mostly likely to be something else all together.