# TinyMCE limit characters typed by users

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I googled a lot for limiting the characters in TinyMCE but nothing is working! How do i create a message box if users type more than 500 characters?

Comment: What version of TinyMCE?

Comment: // 4.0b3 (2013-05-15)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit the number of character in tinyMCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342921/limit-the-number-of-character-in-tinymce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!
New version uses ed.on("KeyDown", function(ed,evt) { instead of ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, evt) {

So function becomes:

```
setup : function(ed) {
                    var max_tekens = <?php echo $max_aantal_tekens_excl_opmaak; ?>;
                    var beschikbaar_voor_opmaak = <?php echo ($max_aantal_tekens_incl_opmaak -
                    $max_aantal_tekens_excl_opmaak); ?>;
                    ed.on("KeyDown", function(ed,evt) {
                      aantal_tekens_zonder_opmaak = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent().replace(/(<
([^>]+)>)/ig,"").length;
                      aantal_tekens_met_opmaak = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent().length;
                      var key = ed.keyCode;
                      $('#omschrijving_wijzigen_tekens').html(max_tekens - aantal_tekens_zonder_opmaak);
                      if (aantal_tekens_met_opmaak > (max_tekens+beschikbaar_voor_opmaak)){
                          alert('U hebt het maximaal aantal tekens nog niet helemaal bereikt, maar u gebruikt veel opmaak dat ook ruimte kost. Verwijder tekens of gebruik minder opmaak (vet, cursief, ondertrepen).');
                          ed.stopPropagation();
                          ed.preventDefault();
                      }
                      else if (aantal_tekens_zonder_opmaak > max_tekens-1 && key != 8 && key != 46){
                           alert('U hebt het maximaal aantal tekens bereikt.');
                           ed.stopPropagation();
                           ed.preventDefault();
                      }
                      else if(aantal_tekens_zonder_opmaak > (max_tekens - 25)){
                          $('#omschrijving_wijzigen_max_tekens').css('color','red');
                      }

                      else {
                          $('#omschrijving_wijzigen_max_tekens').css('color','gray');
                      }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

With TinyMCE 4, you can hook into the on change event:

```
$(document).on('tinymce:changed', function() {
    content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    // check length of content and do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: tinymce.init({
                selector: "textarea",
                menubar : false,
                statusbar : false,
                forced_root_block : false,
                convert_fonts_to_spans : false,
                width : 650,
                height : 120,
                toolbar: "bold italic underline"
            });

$(document).on('tinymce:changed', function() {
    content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    alert('ss');
    // check length of content and do whatever you want
});

Comment: Not sure. I am using this event also in the 4.0 beta perfectly fine (that is where I pulled this code from).