# Character Limit is showing remaining characters in "negative" numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, tinymce-3

I am using tinyMCE version 3, I am using rich-text editor which counts the characters remaining on fly when giving the input. Since maxLength attribute does not work for tinyMCE3. I have hardcoded this way but its counting the blank charcters as well

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    editor_selector: "mceEditor",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_path: false,
    statusbar: true,
    setup: function(editor) {
      editor.onKeyUp.add(function(c) {
        //    var maxCount = document.getElementById(editor.id).maxLength;
        var maxCount = 10;
        console.log(editor.id);
        var txt = $(editor.getBody()).text();
        var txtLen = txt.length;
        var value = maxCount - (txtLen);
        $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContainer()).find("#" + editor.id + "_path_row").html("Remaining chars: " + (value));

        if (txtLen > maxCount) {
          editor.setContent("");
          tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(txt.substring(0, maxCount));
          tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();
        }
      });
    }

  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<textarea id="1" class="mceEditor" cols="100" rows="7" wrap="" maxlength="10">test sample</textarea>
```

[Counting in negative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2UkR.png)

[Counting in negative numbers and setting content to blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAty0.png)

and when I enter 2 characters in between Its removing the last two charcters is there any way I can stop giving the input after it reaches counter "0".

Comment: use `abs` to make it positive `var value = Math.abs(maxCount-(txtLen))`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Its just removing negative and showing as 1,2,3 after 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your issue fully, as there are multiple things going on here.

### Showing remaining characters as negative

I see that, with your code, if you type 11 characters, the 11th character will be deleted, but then remaining characters shows "-1" instead of "0". Is this your complaint? The reason why this is happening is because you trim the text content of the  editor down to maxCount, but your remaining chars value was calculated before the trim occurs, so it still has the value of maxCount - untrimmed length. You could easily remedy this in multiple ways, including changing this:

```
$(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContainer()).find("#" + editor.id + "_path_row").html("Remaining chars: " + (value));
```

to this:

```
$(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContainer()).find("#" + editor.id + "_path_row").html("Remaining chars: " + (value > 0 ? value : 0));
```

### Counting Blank Characters

If you don't want *any* blank characters included in the count, use this:

```
var txtLen = txt.replace(/\s/g,"").length;
```

If you want to trim just the blank characters off the ends, use this:

```
var txtLen = txt.trim().length;
```

Comment: One more thing is happening here when I observed I am giving 2 characters in between so its cutting of the last two because I am using setcontent"" and substring(0,max) is there any other alternative?

Comment: That is happening because you are reverting the content of the editor after it has already changed, so it flashes on the screen for a second before reverting. The way to prevent this is to attach your event listener to the "onKeyDown" event instead of "onKeyUp" - then cancel the event (via event.preventDefault()) if it is going to cause the text length to go over the limit. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840235/11447682 for details.