# TinyMCE Paste Character Length Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, tinymce

I'm using Tiny MCE5 to create input labels. A function has been created below:

```
            setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('keydown', function (e) {
                var maxPermittedChars = 255;
                var inputLength = CountCharacters(textinputid);
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                if (inputLength > maxPermittedChars+1) {
                    if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

The function above is working fine to limit the amount of characters the user can input **however** when I am pasting onto the label, it's enabling text with more than 255 characters and cannot truncate to cap the text to 255 characters. Is there a tinyMCE paste validation that limits the amount of characters that can be pasted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit the number of character in tinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342921/limit-the-number-of-character-in-tinymce)